# Write delete query using GROUP BY, HAVING

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query GROUP BY, HAVING.

Query is working fine now need to delete same records, and when i am trying to delete these record i am getting an error.

**Select Query**

```
SELECT * FROM user_location_history WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(location_date/1000),SYSDATE())>30) AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_location_history WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(location_date/1000),SYSDATE()) < 30) GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(1) > 100) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 200
```

**Delete Query**

```
DELETE FROM user_location_history WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(location_date/1000),SYSDATE())>30) AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_location_history WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(location_date/1000),SYSDATE()) < 30) GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(1) > 100) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 200
```

**Error**

Error Code: 1093
You can't specify target table 'user_location_history' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @Strawberry I have used GROUP_CONCAT in my previous query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around this problem is to wrap the subquery in another subquery:

```
DELETE FROM user_location_history 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(location_date/1000),SYSDATE())>30
       AND 
       user_id IN (
          SELECT user_id 
          FROM (SELECT user_id 
                FROM user_location_history 
                WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,
                                    FROM_UNIXTIME(location_date/1000),
                                    SYSDATE()) < 30
                GROUP BY user_id 
                HAVING COUNT(1) > 100) AS t)
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your select query as nested subquery,then following will work for you

```
DELETE FROM user_location_history
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(location_date/1000),SYSDATE())>30
      AND 
      user_id IN 
          (
            select * from 
            (
             SELECT user_id 
             FROM user_location_history
             WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(location_date/1000),SYSDATE()) < 30
             GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(1) > 100
            )t
          ) 
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 200
```